# Serialization with GSON in a single Entity class

Tags: android, serialization, kotlin, gson, android-room

I have a JSON with a parent called "posts" and I have the respective children. I am using GSON to serialize the fields into my entity(I'am using Room).

I am using a POJO called Post like

```
@Entity
data class Post(
  @SerializableName("somethig")  val something:Int
  @SerializableName("somethig")  val something:Int
)
```

And I am using a class with a List of it

```
class PostParent{
  @Serializablename("posts") listPosts : List<Post> //to call the parent
}
```

Is there any other way to pass the parent JSON name directly in the Entity class instead of doing a class with a single List? I want to avoid this because I have a dao where I need to insert and fetch the data and he only accepts Lists, so I cant have my dao **method** return the class

**Method**

```
override fun loadFromDb(): LiveData<PostParent> { //error in build time
                return postsDao.getPosts() //tried to do postsDao.getPosts().data already
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. Have not tried it myself yet, so you might need to edit some syntax here n there.

```
@Entity
class PostParent{
  @Serializablename("posts") listPosts : List<@Embedded Post>
}

data class Post(
  @SerializableName("somethig")  val something:Int
  @SerializableName("somethig")  val something:Int
)
```

Comment: I cannot put @Embedded inside a List